# IOError: unable to receive websocket message

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, uwsgi

I am in the process of setting up a python websocket app, the basic code that I have right now is this

```
import uwsgi

def application(env, start_response):
    # complete the handshake
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'], env.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', ''))
    while True:
        msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
        uwsgi.websocket_send("Oh!  " + msg)
```

I run this code using

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --http-websockets --wsgi-file server.py
```

The code works correctly and when I use the browser to hit this server I get the expected response. But even though the browser displays the correct response, there is an error in the server logs as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pingserver.py", line 9, in application
    msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
IOError: unable to receive websocket message
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should get that error only when the client (the browser) brutally closes the websocket connection. You can trap it and return from the callable without problems